# How to parse response text from some service?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

so  this is my problem.

I use a prepaid account.

I call *100#, and get response from my phone operator about my account balance.
[response link](http://pokit.org/get/?32b4cc09d70b08de71bc1cd3ad931006.jpg)

This says "You have 1.12 BAM left on you account and you can use it until 02.08.2014.

Here is the question.
I want to make this cal programmatically, from code.
I know it's easy, using PhoneCallTask.

Is there any way to parse this response???

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to parse the response and no way to make the call programmatically (PhoneCallTask just shows the UI with the number filled in and the user has to confirm it)